# How to initialize Unity LevelPlay ads?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, mobile-ad-mediation, ironsource

I'm implementing ads with Unity LevelPlay.
I followed everything in the documentation and installed these adapters:

1. ironSource 7.2.6
2. UnityAds 4.3.29.1

When I test on device, I have two different errors in these situations:

1. If I make a local build and install it immediately using "Build & Run", the game starts, but the call to `IronSource.Agent.init(appKey)` ends up with `INIT_FAILED`. Everything else in the game keeps working except for ads.
2. If I upload the build on Google Play Console for internal testing and install from there, the game doesn't even start and crashes immediately complaining about Google AdMob not being initialized correctly. I don't understand why as I'm not even using AdMob adapter.

You can see both errors in the attached screenshot, unfortunately not being very explicative.
Why could I be getting these errors and what can I try in order to solve them?

Unity Version: 2020.3.42f1;
LevelPlay Version: 7.2.6;

[image: Errors from android logcat]

Answer (score 0):

Unity LevelPlay compatible with Unity version 2021.3

Comment: Where did you find this information? I remember updating to 2020.3.42 just because that version was listed as one of the supported versions in LevelPlay's documentation

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, 2020.3 supports LevelPlay... https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.services.levelplay.html